# expressjs bind all routes except 2 folders?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express, url-routing

In expressjs, how do I bind a route to all urls except /static and /fail

For example, it sound bind to:

```
/users
/books
/books/anything
```

but not bind to

```
/static
/fail
/fail/anything
/static/anything
```

Comment: Sounds like bad design. Just bind to `users`, `books`, etc individually

Comment: @Raynos routing happens on the client side.

Comment: no routing happens on the server. express runs on the server.

Comment: @Raynos express serves one document to all. Actual routing happens on the clientside with backbone.js and html5 pushstate.

Comment: should have mentioned that in the question ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are saying you want to create one route for everything but /static* then here is the command for creating the GET route:

```
app.get(/^((?!\/static).)*$/, function(req, res){

    //Do your thing in here...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

My question was just slightly different and this was the best question/answer combo I found so I wanted to share my solution stolen from Clint's answer. If you need like me to restrict from a list of couple of routes like /static and /fail, the following worked for me:

```
app.get(/^(?!(\/static|\/fail)).*$/, function(req, res, next){

  //Do your thing in here...
});
```