# Is it possible to apply basic authentication / middleware in on routes with a whitelist in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, basic-authentication

I'm implementing a RESTful API with Express in Node, and I'm new to both. I'd like to use basic authentication to control access.

I would like to apply it using something like a whitelist but I'm not sure how to do that.

Blacklisting is easy, I can just pepper my `#VERB` calls with the second argument:

```
app.get('/', asyncAuth, requestHandler);
```

I can take that even further and blacklist everything with:

```
app.all('*', asyncAuth, requestHandler);
```

But I want to apply my basicAuth to every single route, **except** for `POST /users`. Is there an elegant way to do that? Can I use the 'blacklist' approach then selectively remove it from the routes I'd like? I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Interesting question, I guess your question is more of "How to select a negative route", that is, match every route except some routes in express - gracefully. You can try matching routes with regex and negate "/users", something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586197/expressjs-bind-all-routes-except-2-folders ?

Comment: Thank you! I was having trouble wording it. Selecting a negative route is what I'd like to do.  

I considered using a regex, it would work, but it felt a bit like a hack. It seemed like there should be a nicer way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define your route for `POST /users` before the blacklisted routes:

```
app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
  ...
});

app.all('*', asyncAuth, requestHandler);
```

Comment: I can't believe it was this simple and it didn't occur to me! Thank you. I made this change and all my tests are green.

Answer (score 2):

You could maintain a list of regexps that are whitelisted, and match the url against each url in the list, if it matches any then proceed, else require auth

```
app.all('*', asyncAuth);

function asyncAuth(req, res, next) {
    var done = false;
    whitelist.forEach(function(regexp) {
        if (req.url.match(regexp)) {
            done = true;
            next();
        }
    });
    if (!done) requireAuth(next);
}
```

Something along those lines

Comment: Yes! That would work. I had been using `express.basicAuth( function(username, password) {...}` exclusively, so I thought I wouldn't have access to `req`. That's a neat trick.

I'll mark this as the solution unless somebody knows how to do it without this sort of workaround.